# Powershell passing XMLDocument through function calls

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass a `System.XML.XMLDocument` object through function calls, however that object is changed to `System.Object[]` after function call.

More specifically, I have a function like this:

```
function GenerateXml()
{

    [System.XML.XMLDocument]$xmlDoc=New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
    $declaration = $xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes")
    $xmlDoc.AppendChild($declaration)

    [System.XML.XMLElement]$root = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("dummy")
    $root.SetAttribute("Name", "dummy value")
    $xmlDoc.AppendChild($root)
    $xmlDoc
}

[System.XML.XMLDocument]$xmlDoc = GenerateXml
```

This will output an error like:

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument".
```

So what is the best way of passing a XMLDocument through function calls?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Powershell will return all the output from a method to an array. To get the actual return value, you can either get the last member of the output array or just don't output anything else other than what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Your follow up response "output a method to an array" is true, but avoidable. In your example you utilize the .AppendChild() method, which in itself can produce output and therefore a Return value as objects in an array. This scenario can be avoided as

```
$xmlDoc.AppendChild($root) | Out-Null
```